# How convert a native vector<object> to Managed List<Object>

Tags: .net, c++-cli, stdvector

I have in c++ dll a class called Signal. In C++/CLI wrapper I wrap that with SignalWrapper.

I have some trouble when I want to convert from std::vector of Signal to Generic::List of SignalWrapper

Here is what I am trying and I get VS compile errors at first "<"

```
static List<SignalWrapper^>^ NativeToDotNet(vector<Signal> signals)
{
    List<SignalWrapper^> ^signalWrapperList = gcnew List<SignalWrapper^>(signals.size());            

    for (int i = 0; i < signals.size(); i++)
    {
        SignalWrapper ^s = gcnew SignalWrapper(signals[i]);
        s->Name = "MySignal";
        signalWrapperList->Add(s);
    }

    return signalWrapperList;
}
```

Comment: Are the error messages top secret or can you post them here?

Comment: You still need to `.Add` to your list. The size parameter just helps with preventing resizes. [List<T> Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: I did not include the error because I thought it brings nothing new to the table: Error 30 error C2059: syntax error : '>'

Comment: @crashmstr I have edited my snipped as suggested, adding signalWrapperList->Add(s);

Comment: @krs your code compiles just fine, there's no syntax error in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the error. The SignalWrapper Class was not known at the time of this method definition. This was causing the ">" errors.